# How make method start new execution only when finished previous execution

Tags: c#

Hello How make method MethodA start new execution only when finished previous execution?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        MethodB();
        MethodC();
    }

    public static void MethodA ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Stop");
    }

    public static void MethodB()
    {
        Task.Run(() => MethodA());
    }

    public static void MethodC()
    {
        Task.Run(() => MethodA());
    }
}
```

In this case I have this result

```
Hello World
Start
Start
Stop
Stop
```

But I need something like this

```
Hello World
Start
Stop
Start
Stop
```

Comment: Why are you using Task.Run here? What do you think it's buying you?

Comment: Use a lock (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) or semiphore (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @jdweng Why are you suggesting that without knowing the use case?

Comment: I use Task.Run only for example. Actually, I need to call MethodA from different Threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a static locking object and reference that in `MethodA`:

```
private static readonly object _methodALockObject = new object();

public static void MethodA()
{
    lock(_methodALockObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Stop");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `async` and `await`:

```
public static void Main()
{   
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
         await MethodB();
         await MethodC();
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public static void MethodA()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    Console.WriteLine("Stop");
}

public async static Task MethodB()
{
    await Task.Run(() => MethodA());
}

public async static Task MethodC()
{
    await Task.Run(() => MethodA());
}
```

`async` and `await` keywords help to make your asynchronous code to be executed in syncronous order.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is would not be working if we will call MethodB and MethodC from different places

Comment: @LightEffect if you use `async` and `await` it will keep order

Comment: @LightEffect then just use `async` and `await` in another thread.